# Proxy not working in jar but working when compiling in netbeans

Tags: java, jar, proxy

Can anyone help me please with proxy?

I use

```
System.getProperties().put("proxySet", "true");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "proxy.avp.ru");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "proxyUser");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "proxyPassword");
```

and running in Netbeans everything works perfect but when I create the distributive with jar file, app doesn’t work because of proxy. Why does this happen?

Thanks